# Select smallest from the set of possible search results using RE

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the sentence just preceding `[n]` where n is some number entered by the user. If n=5 (as in here), I should get the sentence `Two years later, Fate magazine published "Sea Mystery at Our Back Door",`

```
s = """Coordinates: 25°N 71°W / 25°N 71°W / 25; -71The Bermuda Triangle, also known as the Devil's Triangle,
is a loosely-defined region in the western part of the North Atlantic Ocean, where a number of aircraft and ships are said to have
disappeared under mysterious circumstances. Most reputable sources dismiss the idea that there is any mystery. The vicinity of the
Bermuda Triangle is one of the most heavily traveled shipping lanes in the world, with ships frequently crossing through it for ports
in the Americas, Europe, and the Caribbean islands. Cruise ships and pleasure craft regularly sail through the region, and commercial
and private aircraft routinely fly over it.Popular culture has attributed various disappearances to the paranormal or activity by
extraterrestrial beings. Documented evidence indicates that a significant percentage of the incidents were spurious, inaccurately reported,
or embellished by later authors.In 1964, Vincent Gaddis wrote in the pulp magazine Argosy of the boundaries of the Bermuda Triangle:[1]
three vertices, in Miami, Florida peninsula, in San Juan, Puerto Rico, and in the mid-Atlantic island of Bermuda. Subsequent writers did
not necessarily follow this definition.[2] Some writers gave different boundaries and vertices to the triangle, with the total area varying
from 1,300,000 to 3,900,000 km2 (500,000 to 1,510,000 sq mi).[2] Consequently, the determination of which accidents occurred inside the
triangle depends on which writer reported them.[2] The United States Board on Geographic Names does not recognize the Bermuda Triangle.[2]The
earliest suggestion of unusual disappearances in the Bermuda area appeared in a September 17, 1950 article published in The Miami Herald
(Associated Press)[3] by Edward Van Winkle Jones.[4] Two years later, Fate magazine published "Sea Mystery at Our Back Door",[5]
"""
n=5
regex = "[\]][ ]?.*?\["+str(n)+"\]"

match = re.search(regex, s)
try:
    print(match.group())
except:
    print("Not found")
```

I am not sure how to start my RE. In the code snippet, I've assumed that the previous sentence to the desired would end in `]` and I've taken the sentence after that. Even this isn't showing me the correct result.

It shows:

```
] three vertices, in Miami, Florida peninsula, in San Juan, Puerto Rico, and in the mid-Atlantic island of Bermuda. Subsequent writers did
not necessarily follow this definition.[2] Some writers gave different boundaries and vertices to the triangle, with the total area varying
from 1,300,000 to 3,900,000 km2 (500,000 to 1,510,000 sq mi).[2] Consequently, the determination of which accidents occurred inside the triangle
depends on which writer reported them.[2] The United States Board on Geographic Names does not recognize the Bermuda Triangle.[2]The earliest
suggestion of unusual disappearances in the Bermuda area appeared in a September 17, 1950 article published in The Miami Herald (Associated Press)
[3] by Edward Van Winkle Jones.[4] Two years later, Fate magazine published "Sea Mystery at Our Back Door",[5]
```

How should I just get the last sentence here?

And how should I accomplish this whole task? ie. putting in all the possible situations to the RE. for eg.

1. Previous sentence to the desired, ends in `]`
2. Previous sentence to the desired, ends in `.`
3. There is no previous sentence. (The desired one is the first of the lot)

**P.S.** The desired sentence is a single sentence just preceding `[n]`.

Note: The strings provided above do not have a newline feed (ie. \n) anywhere. I've provided some to clear things up a little bit.

Comment: If `n=3`, will the expected output be `Some writers gave different boundaries and vertices to the triangle, with the total area varying
from 1,300,000 to 3,900,000 km2 (500,000 to 1,510,000 sq mi).[2] Consequently, the determination of which accidents occurred inside the
triangle depends on which writer reported them.[2] The United States Board on Geographic Names does not recognize the Bermuda Triangle.[2]The
earliest suggestion of unusual disappearances in the Bermuda area appeared in a September 17, 1950 article published in The Miami Herald
(Associated Press)`?

Comment: Also, what about `n=1`? I have tried to write a dynamic regex based on the input number, [see a demo here](http://ideone.com/dOlBtO).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No. `n=3` should just show `The earliest suggestion of unusual disappearances in the Bermuda area appeared in a September 17, 1950 article published in The Miami Herald (Associated Press)`

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/3eoUvj). To grab the last sentence occurrence, I enclosed the whole pattern within an optional group, added optional (0+) whitespace pattern at the start of the group and applied a `+` quantifier on it. Now, Group 1 only contains the part captured during the last iteration. The lookahead will fail each `[number]`, so we only get the part without `[number]`s.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But `n=2` should just show the sentence previous to `[2]` ie. `Subsequent writers did not necessarily follow this definition.`

Comment: A regex approach seems meaningless. Split with `r'(\[\d+])'` and you will have indices at odd places and texts at even places. Then just use appropriate tools to split sentences (nltk?) and get your output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If I just assume that the previous sentence to the desired, always ends with `]`. How do I just get `] Two years later, Fate magazine published "Sea Mystery at Our Back Door",` when n=5 with my above approach. It seems to give me a lot (which I've posted above). The reluctant quantifier (?) did not help me to get the shortest one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that (in a general way) and then select the item you want:

```
>>> res = re.findall(r'([^].!?\[]+[.!?]?)(?:\[(\d+)])?',s.strip())
>>> [x[0] for x in res if x[1]=='5'][0]
' Two years later, Fate magazine published "Sea Mystery at Our Back Door",'
```

or you can directly ask:

```
>>> re.search(r'([^].!?\[]+[.!?]?)\[5]', s.strip()).group(1)
' Two years later, Fate magazine published "Sea Mystery at Our Back Door",'
```

Obviously, these two naive approaches stop to work when the sentence contains an abbreviation. In this case you need to add exceptions. But to handle these cases a better way is to extract entire blocks before `[n]` and then to use antlr to get the last sentence.

---

The first approach search for all "sentences" eventually followed with a number between square brackets using the `re.findall` method. When defined, this method returns only capture groups *(and not the whole match)*. In the pattern two capture groups are defined: the first for the sentence, the second for the number; so each item in the list returned by `re.findall` is a tuple with a sentence and a number (or an empty string).

The second line (the list comprehension) is only here to filter the results, to extract the sentence from the first tuple where the number is 5.

Pattern details:

```
( # capture group 1
    [^].!?\[]+ # 1 or more characters that aren't: ] [ . ! ? 
    [.!?]?     # an optional punctuation sign
)
(?: # non-capturing group
    \[
     (\d+) # capture group 2
     ] 
)?  # the non-capturing group is optional
```

Comment: Can you please explain your two approaches and their regex?

Comment: @TheHardRock: I will add soon a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @TheHardRock: there's nothing more to explain, it's exactly the same elements. If there's something particular you don't understand in this line please isolate it and ask about it.

Comment: @TheHardRock: You don't know what is a character class? You should read a regex tutorial in this case.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Given your string example, you can do something like this:

```
import re
n=5
for m in re.finditer(r'\s*([^\[]*?\[(\d+)\])', s):
    if int(m.group(2))==n:
        print m.group(1)
```

Prints:

```
Two years later, Fate magazine published "Sea Mystery at Our Back Door",[5]
```

Comment: When `n=1`, it should just give the sentence preceding `[1]` . ie. `In 1964, Vincent Gaddis wrote in the pulp magazine Argosy of the boundaries of the Bermuda Triangle:` . But this code gives the whole set of sentences preceding the desired one.